# node js error Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

create a login function and I send post requests using Postman
send the correct email and password there is no error
but after I try to send the wrong password then has this error send a wrong email or password then got the error.I read most of the posts on the internet but no solution to my questions. I copied that code in  the YouTube video there is no error in that video

```
{
       
        "email": "testx@gmail.com",
        "password": "1x23456"
    }
```

```
MongoDB Connection Successfully
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:644:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Madhawa\Desktop\Social Media Project\Server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Madhawa\Desktop\Social Media Project\Server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Madhawa\Desktop\Social Media Project\Server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at login (file:///C:/Users/Madhawa/Desktop/Social%20Media%20Project/Server/controllers/Auth.js:21:25)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Node.js v19.8.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

this is my code

```
import CryptoJS from "crypto-js";
import User from "../models/user.js";
import Jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

// login function
export const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        if (!user) {
            res.status(404).json(" User not found ");
        }
        const decryptedPassword = await CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        if (decryptedPassword !== req.body.password) {
            res.status(401).json("Wrong password ");
        }

        res.status(200).json(user);

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
}



// register function
export const register = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY).toString(),
        });
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

}

export const logout = (req, res) => {
    res.send("GET Logout");

}

export const glogin = (req, res) => {
    res.send("POST Google Login");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the "return" statement to ensure that the function execution ends immediately after sending the response. Because you didn't use "return", the program continued to execute even after the password was incorrect, resulting in the error you mentioned.

```
    if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json(" User not found ");
    }

   if (decryptedPassword !== req.body.password) {
            return res.status(401).json("Wrong password");
        }
```